# gtk expander with complex expander widgets

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I have an expander that, instead of using a label, have a box with buttons and labels in it, sort of like a tool bar. The problem is that when I interact with those widgets, the expander is activated instead.

Basically I want the expander to only function when I actually click on the arrow, not the stuff to the left of the arrow... or, maybe even preferred, not the buttons or other clickable surfaces.

It seems the expander intercepts the click events over the buttons instead of letting them fall through to the buttons(not sure if they are reacting too).

This probably could be taken care of in the source code by modifying the behavior of the click events and doing some mouse hit testing. I'm not quite sure how to do this yet as I'm new to gtk but I'm hoping there is an easier way.

basic expander

```
> label
...
```

My expander

```
> label button
...
```

clicking on button does the same as clicking on label or >, which I do not want. I want button to function as a button and not cause the expander to expand in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your approach and if you connect the signal to the button you won't get the behavior you're searching for.

To get that, you need to connect the signal to the expander, let's say, with the `button-press-event` and return True to avoid propagation of the signal.

Doing this you will be able to avoid the expander to expand and eventually control the situation on when it will expand.

Glade file (expand.ui):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkExpander" id="expander1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkBox">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkButton">
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">Action 1</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="expand">False</property>
                    <property name="fill">True</property>
                    <property name="position">0</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkButton">
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">Action 2</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="expand">False</property>
                    <property name="fill">True</property>
                    <property name="position">1</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkButton">
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">Action 3</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="expand">False</property>
                    <property name="fill">True</property>
                    <property name="position">2</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child type="label">
              <object class="GtkButton" id="menub">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Menu</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkImage">
            <property name="width_request">400</property>
            <property name="height_request">300</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="stock">gtk-missing-image</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Python code for some logic:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def onMenuButtonPress(self, widget):
    #uncomment below to recreate the original behavior
    #expander.set_expanded(not expander.get_expanded())
    return True

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("expander.ui")

window = builder.get_object("window1")
menu = builder.get_object("menub")
expander = builder.get_object("expander1")

expander.connect("button-press-event", onMenuButtonPress)

window.connect ("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

If you run the code, you'll see that button presses won't expand the expander. Key presses will though (needed to handle key press events, etc)

Uncomment the indicated line on the code to recreate the intrinsic behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would require something like that. Haven't tested it but that seems to be the way. I've actually move away from the expander because of this since it really offers nothing extra except the expanding feature, which I have to handle anyways for some other visual reasons(I want to automatically contract when the app is not in use, so it will "deexpand" depending on a timer). Thanks again!

Comment: just to reiterate a conditional return with `True` and `False` values would have the same behavior. Thanks. Good luck.